# What is the geometrical meaning of matrix with the first row $(1,0,\cdots,0)$

Tags: matrices, affine-geometry

What is the geometrical meaning of matrix $\mathbf{A}\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ in the form
\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} & \cdots & a_{2n} \\
\vdots & & & \ddots  & \\
a_{n1} & & \cdots & & a_{nn}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
$a_{ij}\in\mathbb{R}$.

Is it some type of an affine transform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it means that the first unit vector $e_1=(1,0,...,0)$ is an eigenvector of the matrix to the eigenvalue 1. In other words, when you consider the action of the matrix on the vector space, the subspace spanned by $e_1$ remains precisely the same. If it would be a 2 instead, this subspace would be scaled by a factor of 2...